# How to use ManagementObjectSearcher in silverlight client side?

Tags: silverlight

I want to use ManagementObjectSearcher in the System.Management namespace to get properties of client system.I'm using Silver light as a client side. Does it possible? Please reply...Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ManagementObjectSearcher doesn't supported in silverlight.

Comment: :Thanks for reply..I want to read system properties like hardisk serial number, processorId etc.  Does we have any other option to read it?